# django get() is returning a tuple instead of the object itself

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.9

I've got several models and I am passing an instance of each of them to my template through the context dictionary:

```
def suite(request, oem_name_slug, project_name_slug, variant_name_slug, suite_name_slug):
    s = Suite.objects.get(slug=suite_name_slug),
    context_dict = dict(
        oem=OEM.objects.get(slug=oem_name_slug),
        project=Project.objects.get(slug=project_name_slug),
        variant=Variant.objects.get(slug=variant_name_slug),
        group=s[0].group,
        suite=s,
    )
    return render(request, r'vtc\suite.html',  context_dict)
```

The issue I'm having is that the first `get()`:

`s = Suite.objects.get(slug=suite_name_slug)`

is returning a tuple with the object I'm trying to retrieve as the first element, instead of returning the object directly as I would expect from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get).  Note that I'm not using `get_or_create()`, which would of course return a tuple.  The other `get()` commands are working as I would expect.

`Suite.objects.get(slug=suite_name_slug)` gives `(<Suite: $SuiteName>,)`

`Project.objects.get(slug=project_name_slug)` gives `<Project: $ProjectName>`

Here are the models for each:

```
class Suite(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='suites')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Suite, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('group', 'name'),
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Project(models.Model):
    oem = models.ForeignKey(OEM, related_name='projects')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('oem', 'name'),
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You have a comma left over on your first line of your function where you define `s`

Comment: Ouch.  That would do it.

Comment: omg. I had the exact same typo. Likely because of cut-n-paste from other code where I was creating a dictionary from the same list of things. Ouch.